# Jquery is not working and I get an error when exporting a file

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to export Excel with css in multiple sheets. I can add the table in multiple sheet with header color. I have tried as in Fiddle and it's working fine [**Working Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/feuvktj5/3/) If I add some jquery code to execute on load its not working.

My fiddle is not working with the following code:

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl1 thead tr').html()).append('
        <th></th>
        ');
         $('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl2 thead tr').html()).append('
    <th></th>
    ');
    $('#tbl1 tbody tr').append('
    <td></td>
    ');
    $('#tbl1 tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $('#joined tbody').append("
    <tr></tr>
    ");
    $('#joined tbody tr').eq(index).append($('#tbl1 tbody tr').eq(index).html());
    });
    $('#tbl2 tbody tr').append('
    <td></td>
    ');
    $('#tbl2 tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $('#joined tbody').append("
    <tr></tr>
    ");
    $('#joined tbody tr').eq(index).append($('#tbl2 tbody tr').eq(index).html());
    });
    });
```

I want this code to merge the table which is another functionality.
Note: what I did wrong in my Fiddle exclude the above code in Fiddle

Comment: It's not really an answer, but why not use a 3rd party component to generate the table and function to convert to CSV, such as https://datatables.net/? it will be much more cleaner & easier to maintain.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is up to how you build a joined copy of your tables.

I suggest to use a concise format:

```
$('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl1 thead tr th').clone());
```

```js
// updated code....
$('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl1 thead tr th').clone());
$('#joined thead tr').append($('#tbl2 thead tr th').clone());
$('#joined tbody').append($('#tbl1 tbody tr').clone());
$('#tbl2 tbody tr').each(function(index) {
    $('#joined tbody tr').eq(index).append($(this).find('td').clone());
});
// ----------------

$('button').click(function() {
    tablesToExcel(['tbl1','tbl2'], ['ProductDay1','ProductDay2'], 'TestBook.xls', 'Excel')

});

var tablesToExcel = (function() {
    var uri = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel;base64,'
            , tmplWorkbookXML = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1252"?><?mso-application progid="Excel.Sheet"?>'
                    + ' <Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel"  xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">'
                    + '     <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">'
                    + '         <Author>Qompare</Author>'
                    + '         <Created>{created}</Created>'
                    + '     </DocumentProperties>'
                    + '     <Styles>'
                    + '         <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">'
                    + '             <NumberFormat ss:Format=""/>'
                    + '         </Style>'
                    + '         <Style ss:ID="Header">'
                    + '             <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom"/>'
                    + '             <Borders>'
                    + '                 <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Right"/>'
                    + '                 <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Left"/>'
                    + '                 <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Top"/>'
                    + '                 <Border ss:Color="#000000" ss:Weight="2" ss:LineStyle="Continuous" ss:Position="Bottom"/>'
                    + '             </Borders>'
                    + '             <Font ss:FontName="Calibri" ss:Size="12" ss:Color="#000000"/>'
                    + '             <Interior ss:Color="#cccccc" ss:Pattern="Solid" />'
                    + '             <NumberFormat/>'
                    + '             <Protection/>'
                    + '         </Style>'
                    + '         <Style ss:ID="Changed">'
                    + '             <Borders/>'
                    + '             <Font ss:Color="#ff0000"></Font>'
                    + '             <Interior ss:Color="#99CC00" ss:Pattern="Solid"></Interior>'
                    + '             <NumberFormat/>'
                    + '             <Protection/>'
                    + '         </Style>'
                    + '         <Style ss:ID="Missed">'
                    + '             <Borders/>'
                    + '             <Font ss:Color="#ff0000"></Font>'
                    + '             <Interior ss:Color="#ff0000" ss:Pattern="Solid"></Interior>'
                    + '             <NumberFormat/>'
                    + '             <Protection/>'
                    + '         </Style>'
                    + '         <Style ss:ID="Decimals">'
                    + '             <NumberFormat ss:Format="Fixed"/>'
                    + '         </Style>'
                    + ' </Styles>'
                    + ' {worksheets}'
                    + '</Workbook>'
            , tmplWorksheetXML = '<Worksheet ss:Name="{nameWS}">'
                    + ' <ss:Table>'
                    + '     {rows}'
                    + ' </ss:Table>'
                    + '</Worksheet>'
            , tmplCellXML = '           <ss:Cell{attributeStyleID}{attributeFormula}>'
                    + '             <ss:Data ss:Type="{nameType}">{data}</ss:Data>'
                    + '         </ss:Cell>'
            , base64 = function(s) { return window.btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(s))) }
            , format = function(s, c) { return s.replace(/{(\w+)}/g, function(m, p) { return c[p]; }) }
    return function(tables, wsnames, wbname, appname) {
        var ctx = "";
        var workbookXML = "";
        var worksheetsXML = "";
        var rowsXML = "";

        for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
            if (!tables[i].nodeType) tables[i] = document.getElementById(tables[i]);
            for (var j = 0; j < tables[i].rows.length; j++) {
                rowsXML += '        <ss:Row>'
                for (var k = 0; k < tables[i].rows[j].cells.length; k++) {
                    var dataType = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-type");
                    var dataStyle = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-style");
                    var dataValue = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-value");
                    dataValue = (dataValue)?dataValue:tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].innerHTML;
                    if(!isNaN(dataValue)){
                        dataType = 'Number';
                        dataValue = parseFloat(dataValue);
                    }
                    var dataFormula = tables[i].rows[j].cells[k].getAttribute("data-formula");
                    dataFormula = (dataFormula)?dataFormula:(appname=='Calc' && dataType=='DateTime')?dataValue:null;
                    ctx = {  attributeStyleID: (dataStyle=='Changed' || dataStyle=='Missed'|| dataStyle=='Header')?' ss:StyleID="'+dataStyle+'"':''
                        , nameType: (dataType=='Number' || dataType=='DateTime' || dataType=='Boolean' || dataType=='Error')?dataType:'String'
                        , data: (dataFormula)?'':dataValue
                        , attributeFormula: (dataFormula)?' ss:Formula="'+dataFormula+'"':''
                    };
                    rowsXML += format(tmplCellXML, ctx);
                }
                rowsXML += '        </ss:Row>'
            }
            ctx = {rows: rowsXML, nameWS: wsnames[i] || 'Sheet' + i};
            worksheetsXML += format(tmplWorksheetXML, ctx);
            rowsXML = "";
        }
        ctx = {created: (new Date()).getTime(), worksheets: worksheetsXML};
        workbookXML = format(tmplWorkbookXML, ctx);
        var link = document.createElement("A");
        link.href = uri + base64(workbookXML);
        link.download = wbname || 'Workbook.xls';
        link.target = '_blank';
        document.body.appendChild(link);
        link.click();
        document.body.removeChild(link);
    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Export to Excel</button>

<table id="tbl1" class="table2excel">
    <thead>
    <tr>

        <th data-style="Header">Product</th>
        <th data-style="Header">Price</th>
        <th data-style="Header">Available</th>
        <th data-style="Header">Count</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td data-style="Changed">Bred</td>
        <td data-style="Missed">1</td>
        <td>037.57834600204239857</td>
        <td data-style="Header">3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Butter</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<hr>

<table id="tbl2" class="table2excel">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Product</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>Available</th>
        <th>Count</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>Bred</td>
        <td>7.5</td>
        <td>8</td>
        <td>9</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Butter</td>
        <td>14</td>
        <td>15</td>
        <td>16</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>

<table id="joined" class="table2excel">
    <thead>
        <tr></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```